# How to display states of a country if two specific countries are chosen from a list of countries in Angular ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a list of countries, and the client has the option to choose two of these. When the client uses the checkbox tick to choose two countries (by clicking on the checkboxes of two countries), we need to display the states in those two countries using ng-repeat.

Can someone please help me with a small example of the unordered lists and how to use ng-repeat in this scenario?

I am new to Angular.

Answer (score 0):

As far as the HTML, something like the below is a very simple example of what you may end up with. You could use two `ng-repeat`s; one for each country selected, and another for each state within each country:

```
<div ng-repeat="country in countries">
  <h1>country.name</h1>
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="state in country.states">
      <p>state.name</p>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Matt, thank you very much, let me use it in my code and let you know in sometime

Answer (score 0):

You can create checkboxes which add a "checked" property to the countries. And then a repeat which repeats only checked ones.

View

```
  <p>
    Choose {{limit}} countries:
  </p>
  <p ng-repeat="country in countries">
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="country.checked" ng-disabled="(countries | filter:{checked:true}).length >= limit"> {{country.name}}
  </p>

  <p>
    Result
  </p>
  <div ng-repeat="country in countries | filter:{checked:true}">
    <h1>{{country.name}}</h1>
    <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="state in country.states">
        <p>{{state}}</p>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>

</div>
```

Controller

```
angular.module("app", [])
  .controller("mainCtrl", function($scope) {

    $scope.limit = 2;

    $scope.countries = [{
      "name": "Finland",
      "states": [
        "statename1",
        "statename2"
      ]
    }, {
      "name": "Sweden",
      "states": [
        "statename3",
        "statename4"
      ]
    }, {
      "name": "Norway",
      "states": [
        "statename5",
        "statename6"
      ]
    }];

  });
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/ptfg5xs0/1/